# open sqllitle database javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite

I was given a "mybase.db" database built in sqllite3, I'm trying to open it using javascript (I'm in charge of creating a web interface to it), and I just can't make it to open; this is my code so far:

```
var db;

$(document).ready(function(){
onDeviceReady();
});


// ******  DB FUNCTIONS ********
function onDeviceReady()
{
    db = openDatabase('mydb.db', '1.0', 'mythings', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM mytable', [], function (tx, results)
        {
            alert(results.rows.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
            {
                alert(results.rows.item(i).device_id);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

when I do the SELECT operation it doesn't show anything (I think beacause it creates an empty DB)

I really need this to work!, if you could help me to open the database i would really apreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course... sqllite is creating a new database since javascript executes in the client side and the db is in server side, what I needed was some server side tecnologies like php,django,web2py,etc.